# Function/method with row.entity.xx field as parameter in ui-grid ng-if

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid, angular-ng-if

Tried

```
<div ng-if="[1,2,3].indexOf(1) > -1">...</div>
```

which is **working**, but when i changed it to

```
<div ng-if="[1,2,3].indexOf(row.entity.id) > -1">...</div>
```

where `row.entity.id` = 1, it seemed not be able to get the `row.entity.id` value. Also

```
<div ng-if="row.entity.id == 1">...</div>
```

is **working**.

Any idea?

**Update**:

```
<div ng-if="(1 + 1) == 2">...</div>
```

working.

```
<div ng-if="row.entity.id == 1">...</div>
```

working.

```
<div ng-if="(row.entity.id + 1) == 2">...</div>
<div ng-if="(parseInt(row.entity.id) + 1) == 2">...</div>
<div ng-if="((row.entity.id | number) + 1) == 2">...</div>
```

all NOT working.

Did i do it wrong in converting to int? Or is there a way i can check its class? Also tried

```
<div ng-if="(typeof row.entity.id) == \'string\'">...</div>
```

Comment: It may be possible of row.entity.id value is **String**

Comment: Try this <div ng-if="[1,2,3].indexOf(row.entity.id | number) > -1">...</div>

Comment: Hi @ManishBalodia, i tried it but not working. Quite new to AngularJS/ui-grid, i tried a couple examples below,